# $|G|=p^2$ then $G \cong \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ or $G \cong \mathbb Z_{p} \times \mathbb Z_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Problem

Let $G$ be a group with $|G|=p^2$ for some prime $p$, then $G \cong \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ or $G \cong \mathbb Z_{p} \times \mathbb Z_{p}$.

I think I came up with a solution to this problem but I am not so sure it is correct, I would appreciate if someone could take a loot at it and check if I've made any mistakes, he or she is also encouraged to post an alternative solution to my own.

Suppose $G \not \cong \mathbb Z_{p^2}$. It is easy to see that every element $x \in G$ must satisfy $ord(x)<p^2$, because if not, then $|\langle x\rangle|=p^2=|G|$, which implies $G=\langle x\rangle \cong \mathbb Z_{p^2}$.

First lets show that there are at least two elements $x,y \in G$ with (1) $ord(x)=ord(y)=p$ and (2) $\langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle=\{1\}$. It is very easy to show (1) so I am not going to prove it. As for (2), suppose for all elements $x,y \in G$ of order $p$ we have $\langle x\rangle=\langle y\rangle$. We can write $G=\langle x\rangle \cup (G \setminus \langle x\rangle)$ for some $x$ with $ord(x)=p$. But then $\{1\}=G \setminus \langle x\rangle$, so $p^2=|G|=|\langle x\rangle|+|\{1\}|=p+1$, which is clearly absurd.

By (1) and (2) we have two elements $x,y \in G$ of order $p$ with $\langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle=\{1\}$. It follows $G=\langle x\rangle\cdot_s\langle y\rangle$, i.e., $G$ is the intern semidirect product of $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y\rangle$. Since $\langle x\rangle, \langle y\rangle \cong \mathbb Z_p$, then $G =\langle x\rangle\cdot_s\langle y\rangle \cong \mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Your 'but then $\{1\}=G\backslash\langle x\rangle$' doesn't seem to immediately follow from the statements before it; you might want to flesh that out more.

Comment: (Incidentally, I've TeXified your post more, fixing brackets and such; I encourage having a look at http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols as a resource for the various math symbols.  You might want to consider using $e$ for your group identity instead of $1$ since the latter has an arithmetic meaning that's _not_ generally consistent with being the identity, but that's a personal choice...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear in your proof why $G$ is the semi-direct product of $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$ and why it turns out this is actually a direct product. You must check a final condition: that $\langle x \rangle$ is normal in $G$ for the first, and that both $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$ are normal in $G$ for the second.

Do you see why this is the case?

Comment: Since the order of $G$ is $p^2$, then $G$ is abelian, so both $<x>$ and $<y>$ are normal. If I call $H=<x>.<y>$, then $H$ is a group by normality of, in this case, the two groups. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|H|= |\langle x \rangle. \langle y \rangle|=\dfrac{|\langle x \rangle . \langle y \rangle|}{| \langle x \rangle \cap \langle y \rangle|}=p^2$, it follows $H=G$, so by definition of internal semidirect product, we have $G=\langle x \rangle ._s \langle y \rangle$. I'll keep thinking how to justify the other part and why I need normality of both subgroups.

Comment: Recall that an internal semi-direct product are two subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $HK = G$, $H \cap K = 1$ and either $H$ or $K$ is normal. An internal direct product is the same, except both groups have to be normal. So once you have normality, you don't need to do any more work.

Comment: Also, while it is true that $G$ is abelian, this can be viewed more generally. If $G$ is any finite group and $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, then any subgroup of index $p$ is normal.

Comment: Semidirect product of $N$ and $H$ is usually denoted by $N \rtimes H$, where $N$ is the normal subgroup (the command is \rtimes). A direct product of $N$ and $H$ is $N \times H$ (the command is \times).

Comment: @Leppala: This notation is for external semi-direct products. We are referring to internal semi-direct products where the notation $HK$ makes sense.